# am I unable to hide div element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide July 2019 the element using jquery(i have no prior experience with Jquery)

I have tried this jquery to hide the July 2019

```
 $(function() {
  $("a:not([row='2'])").hide();
});
```

But it hides both June and July.
   The sample code snippet is here

```
<div role="row" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="1" style="height: 26px;">

<a style="cursor:pointer; color:#F96302; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600">JUNE 2019</a>
</div>
<div role="row" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="2" style="height: 26px;">
<a style="cursor:pointer; color:#F96302; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600">JULY 2019</a></div>
```

I just need to hide `July 2019` using jquery

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to look for row =2 on the a when its actually decorated on the div. Flip a to div in jquery and you will be good to go.

and if you are using "not" then it would be row 1 and not row 2

```
$("div:not([row='1'])").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/),

```
$(function() {
  $('a:contains("JULY 2019")').hide();
});
```

---

```js
$(function() {
  $('a:contains("JULY 2019")').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="row" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="1" style="height: 26px;">

<a style="cursor:pointer; color:#F96302; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600">JUNE 2019</a>
</div>
<div role="row" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="2" style="height: 26px;">
<a style="cursor:pointer; color:#F96302; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600">JULY 2019</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use div as a selector instead of  tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("div:not([row='2'])").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="row" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="1" style="height: 26px;">

<a style="cursor:pointer; color:#F96302; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600">JUNE 2019</a>
</div>
<div role="row" class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="2" style="height: 26px;">
<a style="cursor:pointer; color:#F96302; text-decoration: none; font-weight:600">JULY 2019</a></div>
```

```js
$("div:not([row='2'])").hide();
```